# Write to a different file on each iteration

Tags: python, opencv

I want to save images to a new file on each iteration:

```
 str1='vid_result'
 str2=str1+str(ret)
 cv2.imwrite(str(str2),im)
```

Where `ret` is a counter.

But I receive the error:

```
Could not find a writer for the specified extension in function cv::imwrite_.
```

Actually, `cv2.imwrite('vid_result',im)` works fine, so I need to find a proper way to send a filename as a first argument.

P.S. The `str2` is a string and its output is `vid_result1`.

Comment: if `str2` is a string already (which it seems to be) what is the point of `str(str2)`? In any event -- what *is* `str2`?

Comment: @JohnColeman, It's a string, i did that to ensure myself that it IS a string

Comment: Why no file extension in the file name? Something like `.csv`?

Comment: @JohnColeman Well, extension doesnt affect the work

Comment: show the actual code with full traceback, and put a print statement of str2 right before it fails

Answer (score -1):

It sounds ("writer for the specified extension") like it is trying to figure out how to write the image based on the file name and failing.  Print out the value of `str2` and I think that will make the problem obvious.

Comment: this seems more like a comment than an answer